# Setting custom HTTP request headers in an URL object doesn't work

Tags: java, url, http-headers, http-authentication, urlconnection

I am trying to fetch an image from an IP camera using HTTP. The camera requires HTTP basic authentication, so I have to add the corresponding request header:

```
URL url = new URL("http://myipcam/snapshot.jpg");
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", 
  "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode("user:pass".getBytes())));

// outputs "null"
System.out.println(uc.getRequestProperty("Authorization"));
```

I am later passing the `url` object to `ImageIO.read()`, and, as you can guess, I am getting an HTTP 401 Unauthorized, although `user` and `pass` are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried `new URL("http://user:pass@myipcam/snapshot.jpg")`, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved. It didn't work because I was passing `url` to `ImageIO.read()`.

Instead, passing `uc.getInputStream()` got it working.

Answer (score 3):

In class [`sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-sun/net/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java.htm), which extends `java.net.HttpURLConnection`, the following method `getRequestProperty(String key)` was overridden to return `null` when requesting security sensitive information.

```
public String getRequestProperty(String key) {
    // don't return headers containing security sensitive information
    if (key != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < EXCLUDE_HEADERS.length; i++) {
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase(EXCLUDE_HEADERS[i])) {
            return null;
        }
        }
    }
    return requests.findValue(key);
}
```

Here is the declaration for `EXCLUDE_HEADERS`:

```
// the following http request headers should NOT have their values
// returned for security reasons.
private static final String[] EXCLUDE_HEADERS = {
    "Proxy-Authorization", "Authorization" };
```

That's why you're having a `null` on `uc.getRequestProperty("Authorization")`. Have you tried using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) from Apache?

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the reason for getting `null`. But why does it return HTTP 401? Is it possible that the "Authorization" property is not set at all?

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev, if `uc extends HttpURLConnection` then typecast it to `HttpURLConnection` and get the `InputStream` of the error by calling `getErrorStream()`. That contains the message of the HTTP 401 error. Other than that, I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to subclass `URLConnection` or `HttpURLConnection` and override the `getRequestProperty()` method?

Comment: I tried `HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()`, but the outcome is the same. My problem is not actually with `getRequestProperty`, but with the unsent Authorization header.

Comment: then perhaps override the `openConnection` method?